# How to stop showing the Dropbox green checkmarks across every photo?

Tags: ubuntu, dropbox

It's good that Dropbox shows its blue icon to indicate a file is currently getting sync'ed ... however the big green check-marks which are shown to indicate the file has finished its sync are entirely unnecessary and obstructive especially since they are shown in perpetuity

[image: Folders with green checkmark]
I am on Ubuntu and following technique will temporarily remove the green checkmarks simply by removing the offending Dropbox green check-mark file

```
cd ~/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-23.3.16/images/emblems
mv emblem-dropbox-uptodate.icon emblem-dropbox-uptodate.icon~ignore
mv emblem-dropbox-uptodate.png emblem-dropbox-uptodate.png~ignore
```

This is a temporary fix since checkmarks will reappear upon the next Dropbox app update which are frequent.

Does anyone know how to disable these green check marks?

As a band-aid, until the root cause is fixed, I execute this bash script to make the offending green checkmark image files go away

```
#!/bin/bash

#  remove Dropbox green checkmark files if they exist

cd ~/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-*/images/emblems/

green_icon=emblem-dropbox-uptodate.icon
green_png=emblem-dropbox-uptodate.png

[[ -f "${green_icon}" ]] && mv "${green_icon}" "${green_icon}"~ignore

[[ -f "${green_png}"  ]] && mv "${green_png}"   "${green_png}"~ignore
```

Comment: Failing a better answer you could put your mv commands in a shell script and have it run on boot or something or at least be a desktop shortcut that you can easily run after an update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the answer above about the location of the icon
cd ~/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-*/images/emblems/

I opened the file in gimp, scaled it way down, keeping the canvas size the same and saved over it.

Now I have the green checkbox, but it's not obtrusive.  I like scaling up the icon view to 400%.  Pretty obtrusive without a resize.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to hide Dropbox's overlay icons, but the process is different depending on your operating system. Unfortunately, I could only find instructions on disabling the icon on Windows and Mac.

### Windows

> 1. Open Windows Registry Editor (<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, type in `regedit`, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>).
> 2. Then go to: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers`
> 3. Under `ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers` key you will find keys of Dropbox, SkyDrive, and any other service that you may have installed
>      on your computer.
>
> [image: DropboxExt1 in regedit]
>
> 4. For Dropbox, simply rename the key `DropboxExt1` to something like `DropboxExt1-D` so Windows cannot find the key value in the registry.
> 5. Once done, restart your computer, or restart explorer using Task Manager.
>
> That’s it. You won’t find any more overlay icons on your synced files.
>   To get the icons back, remove the text that you appended on the
>   key(s).

- [Via SumTips.com](http://sumtips.com/2012/10/remove-green-check-mark-icon-overlay.html)

---

### Mac OS

> Open Finder and locate the Dropbox application, which you likely have
>   stored in your Applications folder. Right-click on it and select
>   **Show Package Contents**.
>
> [image: Dropbox in finder]
>
> You'll see a lone folder titled **Contents**. Open it and then open
>   the **PlugIns** folder. Inside the PlugIns folder will be a lone file,
>   **garcon.appex**. Right-click on this file and again select **Show Package Contents**.
>
> [image: garcon.appex in finder]
>
> Again, you'll see a lone folder titled **Contents**. Open it and then
>   open the **Resources** folder. Inside will be a number of folders and
>   four overlay files. Change the name of the **overlay-uptodate.icns**
>   file, which is the file for the green check mark icons. I just added
>   edit to the end of it. This way, if I find I miss the feeling of
>   warmth and security that green sea of check marks provides, I can just
>   go back and remove my edit suffix and return the file name to its
>   original name, thus restoring Dropbox's green check marks in Finder.
>
> [image: Green checkbox icon file]
>
> You will need to relaunch Finder for the change to take effect. Hold
>   down the **Option** key and right-click the Finder icon in the Dock,
>   and then click **Relaunch**.
>
> [image: Relaunching Finder]
>
> When Finder returns, your Dropbox folder will be free of the green
>   check marks.
>
> [image: Dropbox without green checkmarks]

- [Via cnet.com](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/get-rid-of-dropboxs-green-check-mark-icons-in-os-x-finder/)

Answer (score 0):

on linux I just execute the following script to make those green icons disappear (until next Dropbox update ;-()

```
#!/bin/bash

# ... on OSX look at   finder -> applications -> dropbox -> Show Package Contents -> Resources -> overlay-update.icons  <--- rename xxx.~ignore


cd ~/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-*/images/emblems/

green_icon=emblem-dropbox-uptodate.icon
green_png=emblem-dropbox-uptodate.png

[[ -f "${green_icon}" ]] && mv "${green_icon}" "${green_icon}"~ignore

[[ -f "${green_png}"  ]] && mv "${green_png}"   "${green_png}"~ignore
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to remove the green ticks by simply stopping using Smart Backup, found in the settings in the dropbox app.

Answer (score -1):

If you're just browsing files without adding anything, 
exiting out of Dropbox and refreshing the Dropbox folder 
page removes the green check marks.  When you need to 
sync some files, just open Dropbox again.

This also works with Mega cloud storage.  Just exit out 
of Mega to stop syncing and refresh the Mega folder page.